# Plotting these complex inequalities on a complex plane.

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

[image]

For the first part a) it is very clear a circle with center at -i. With common sense using equation of a circle.

For the 2nd part i'm having some trouble. My steps..

b)  x+2y<3

$$(\sqrt{x})^2 + (\sqrt{2y})^2 < (\sqrt{3})^2$$
   which i guess is an ellipse?

can you always solve algebraicly and plot for the polynom? but sometimes it doesn't work.
i always substitute z=a+ib and get an equation of a straight line inequality instead of a circle. How to find a reliable way to do this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check your reasoning on (a) - $|z+i|<1$ is a circle centered at $-i$ - but we have $>$ instead of $<$, so we actually have that it's the whole plane *minus* a circle.

Also, as for $b$, I don't think your step of changing the absolute values to $\sqrt{x}^2$ is much use - and I think it's mislead you. *Yes*, you're right that that sum *looks* like the form for an ellipse, but it's in terms of $\sqrt{x}$ and $\sqrt{y}$, not in terms of $x$ and $y$, like it would have to be to really be an ellipse.

What would be better is to consider the four quadrants individually - e.g. in the quadrant where $\text{Re}(z)$ and $\text{Im}(z)$ are positive, we have that $$x+2y<3$$
which is conveniently just a little triangular slice with vertices at $0$, $3$ and $\frac{3}2i$. You can repeat this for every quadrant, negating $\text{Re}(z)$ and $\text{Im}(z)$ as necessary on each quadrant for the absolute value.

Comment: i understood your point on the first one. But the second one simple rather trivial.. isnt it an equation of a straight line then? or how do you plot it like a traingle?

Comment: for part b i get an equation of a straight line.

Comment: It's a straight line *in each quadrant* - so when you cut off just the part of the line in the quadrant, it's a triangle. For instance, if $\text{Re}(z)$ is negative, the equation reads $-x+2y<3$, due to the absolute value. You could plot all four lines generated by negating $x$ or $y$ or neither or both, and the area in the middle would be the answer.

Comment: can u post a rough sketch please. would appreciate it alot